# startup probes not working with exec as expected

Tags: kubernetes

I have a sample webapp and redis  that I am running in Kubernetes.
I am using probes for the basic checks like below
Now I want to make sure that redis is up and running before the application.
below code snippet is from webapp.
when I run a command `nc -zv <redis service name> 6379` it works well, but when I use it as command in `startupProbe` it gives me errors. I think the way I am passing command is not right, can someone help me understand what is wrong

error I get

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "nc -zv redis 6379": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

```
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 5000
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 5
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
         path: /
         port: 5000
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 5
    startupProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - nc -zv redis 6379
      failureThreshold: 20
      periodSeconds: 5
```

Comment: You need to break the `command:` into multiple shell words.  I'd suggest skipping this entirely, though.  What would happen if Redis failed after the application starts up; can your application recover (or crash) in the same way if it's not available at startup time?

Comment: App does have dependency on redis,and yes if redis fails after application start up , then my application wont work either.
Like you said I need to break this in shell words, would you mind give me a snippet of it, that how it will look like?

Comment: My main  goal to have redis up before application is, and I am trying to achieve that using startupProbe, as I don't see any other option

Comment: If you do nothing, and your application can't connect to Redis, say it crashes and the container exits.  Kubernetes will attempt to restart it, adding some delay after the first couple of times.  Eventually Redis will be available and your container will start up successfully.  (Or it's not, and the Pod will be in CrashLoopBackOff state, and you can see why in its logs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command has to be entered in proper format as it is an array. The below code is in expected format.

```
        startupProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - nc 
            - -zv
            - redis 
            - "6379"
          failureThreshold: 30
          periodSeconds: 5
```

Comment: Does this change solved your issue and error doesn't appear?

Comment: yes it did solve my issue

Comment: Could you edit your answer adding explanation what you changed and why it work now as David Maze explained in comment. It is good practice to add [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with explanation if you solved your issue. It will be helpful in future for other people

Comment: it solved my issue as well. the only thing that's impossible to do is to run several commands using this approach.